# How to reference comments in github.com?

Tags: github

How to write a reference like

```
I guess my comment [mask][N] was nonsense
```

where `[N]` is the number of the comment made in the current conversation and `[mask]` something to tell github to reference comments (like `#` does for issues)?

A full or partial quote would be a workaround, but requires either to enlarge the conversation with text which is unnecessary (consider 25 linues of comment against `:3`) or to write the partial quote `> [5 start words] ... [5 end words]` which is hard to read and takes seconds to create and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need copy the URL in the date of comment and paste in the issue or PR.

Ex: https://github.com/Clowl/asio/issues/20

The link to comment is in date "yograterol commented on here --> **21 Apr**" (see pic)

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I guess I only hovered over `commented` which for some nonsense reason isn't included in the link...